# How to count number of duplicate and unique values in each column using Spark Scala Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I want to take the duplicate and unique count of the each column(column values are dynamic input)of the dataframe.

My code:

```
  var s = "id|name|nct_id|etc"
  var result = s.replace('|', ',')
  val dup_cols = result.split(",").toList
  val conditionDF=  patternsqlDF.select(patternsqlDF.col("id"), patternsqlDF.col("name"))

val aggCols2 = conditionDF.columns.map(dup_cols => {  
val colDF=patternsqlDF.select(patternsqlDF.col(dup_cols))    colDF.withColumn("count",count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(dup_cols))).where($"count">1).show()
  })
```

Example Input DF: (inputDF.Show())

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Id            | name       | Phone           | Email               |  city         |
   + --------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------+
   |   2           | Ram        | 9876543210      | ram@gmail.com       | Pune          |
   |   3           | Sam        | 8765432104      | sam@gmail.com       | Bangalore     |
   |   4           | Sugu       | 7655555555      | sam@gmail.com       | Hyderabad     |
   |   3           | Sam        | 8765042222      | sam@gmail.com       | Chennai       |
   |   5           | Sugu       | 9876543210      | sugu95@gmail.com    | Mysore        |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Output Dataframe Should be Like this

1. Duplicate Count Output DF

Here I want to take the duplicate count of each column(Note:- columns are dynamic input- this may increase or decrease, the data frame contains any no. of columns)

```
              ----------------------------------------------------------------
              |  name       | Phone           | Email       | city           | 
              +-------------+-----------------+------------------------------+
              |  4          |   2             |  3          | 0              |
               ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

2.Unique Count Output DF

I want to take the unique records count of each column (Note:- columns are dynamic input- this may increase or decrease)

```
              ----------------------------------------------
              |  name       |  Email       | city           |  
              +-------------+--------------+----------------+
              |  1          |   2          | 5              |
               ----------------------------------------------
```

Can anybody tell me how I can count duplicate value and unique value for each column in the data frame?

Comment: Can you add more detail on how you define duplicate and unique, How is name 4, Phone 2 and Email 3  also in Unique name 1 email 2?

Comment: I think by duplicate he means the total sum of records with count > 1 and by unique he means the total sum of records with count == 1.

Comment: for example, I want to count duplicate record count in the particular column like name,  It should return 4. If I want unique column count for name column, it should return 1.

Comment: this is not a duplicate question. Here I am asking each column duplicate/unique count. the duplicate link has the combination of 2 or 3 attributes.

Comment: I'm just giving a try.. almost half done.. btw are you from QA team.. your questions are always concerned with meta-programming

Comment: Not sure, how this is a duplicate of the cited Q&A ? @Revathi, did you have any luck with this ? If not, better create a new question.